# How to Show Hide Button and Text under a Flex justify content box

Tags: html, css

Please review my code for a Flexbox layout that displays a "Learn More" button and text description when hovered over. I attempted to use the .column:hover + .hide selector, but the .hide class does not seem to be functioning properly.

I have a few questions regarding the functionality and design of the code:

- Initially, I want the button to be hidden and only shown on the right
  side when hovered over.
- I also want the description text to be displayed when hovering over the button.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #10172b;
        font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: #10172b;
    }
    .column {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        transition: flex 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #293346;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .column:hover {
        flex: 0 0 60%;
    }
    .responsive {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .purple {
        align-self: flex-end;
        background-color: #6d38f1;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px 24px;
        border: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .purple:hover {
        background-color: #15E333;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .description:hover + .hide {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="column">
        <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
          <h3>Services</h3>
          <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png"  alt="Services" class="responsive"/>
        <button class="purple hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
          <h3>Warehouse</h3>
          <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png"  alt="Warehouse"  class="responsive"/>
        <button class="purple">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
          <h3>IIOT</h3>
          <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png"  alt="IIOT"  class="responsive"/>
        <button class="purple">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this is what you want.
I added 2 rules at the bottom of the CSS.

The last rule is searching for a parent that contains a hovered button. When found, it displays the text for the first column.

More information on the `:has()` selector can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #10172b;
  font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #10172b;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: flex 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #293346;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.column:hover {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.purple {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: #6d38f1;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.purple:hover {
  background-color: #15E333;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Added */

.column:hover>button.hide {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column:has(button:hover) p.description {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
      <h3>Services</h3>
      <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png" alt="Services" class="responsive" />
    <button class="purple hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
      <h3>Warehouse</h3>
      <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png" alt="Warehouse" class="responsive" />
    <button class="purple">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
      <h3>IIOT</h3>
      <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x400.png" alt="IIOT" class="responsive" />
    <button class="purple">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this could you please update this snippet. I want to show the description text when hover on the whole column not only on the button. Thank you! Want to show both button and text on column hover.

Comment: Hi Gerard, This code also not working on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```css
body {
    background-color: #10172b;
    font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
    color: #ffffff;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #10172b;
    width: 1100px;
}
.widget-image {
    padding-top:100px;
    display: inline-block;    
}
.column {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    transition: flex 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #293346;
    margin-right: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.column:hover {
    flex: 0 0 550px;
    transition: 1.5s;
}
.column:hover .widget-image {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.column:hover .learn-more-button {
    margin: 0px;
}
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.learn-more-button {
    background-color: #6d38f1;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.learn-more-button:hover {
    background-color: #15E333;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
/* Added */

.column:hover>button.hide {
    display: inline-block;
}
.column:hover>p.hide {
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.description {
    width: 350px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.column:hover .description {
    display: block;
}
.heading-prix {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family:  Poppins, "sans-serif";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
     <p class="heading-prix">Services</p>
     <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
     <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="Services" class="widget-image responsive"  />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide" style="align-items: flex-end;"  >Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <p class="heading-prix">Warehouse</p>
    <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="Warehouse" class="widget-image responsive" />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
      <p class="heading-prix">IIOT</p>
      <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>       
    <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="IIOT" class="widget-image responsive" />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```